# Number of real root of the equation $8x^3-6x+1$ lying between -1 and 1 is

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Number of real root of the equation $8x^3-6x+1$ lying between -1 and 1 is:

I am lagging in solving the inequality portion.

Let the roots be $m_1,m_2,m_3$ then $m_1m_2m_3=-\frac{1}{8}$ which means that not all of the roots are -ve. But after this I am unable to formulate the equality to find the desired.

It might be simple but I am missing a very solid idea to complete and find the desired.

Comment: You need arguments like this: $f(0)=1,f(\frac{1}{2})=-1$, so there is at least one root between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: By testing the value of the polynomial at $-1$, $0$ and $1$, there is at least a real root between $-1$ and $0$. So the product of the other roots is positive, and the sum of the other roots is also positive. Then you can test whether there is a local minimum below zero for $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

for $y=8x^3-6x+1$ and $y'=24x^2-6$ . So ve have two stationary points for $x=\pm1/2$.

Now you can see that there is a positive valued max at $x=-1/2$ and a negative valued min at $x=1/2$ and the function is negative for $x=-1$ and positive for $x=1$.

Use continuity ([intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)) to show that there are three roots in $[-1,1]$

Comment: @IrregularUser Would it be normal to check continuity for a cubic like this when it is clear, by inspection? The user below has even recognized the numbers as coming up in a trigonometric identity. Unfortunately that wouldn't serve as a general method - only good for a few identities that can be recognized.

Comment: @Benedict Why is this directed at me? I'm very confused at what your comment is supposed to be about so I'll answer as best I can. "Would it be normal to check continuity for a cubic like this when it is clear, by inspection?" Before using the IVT you need to make sure that your function is continuous on a closed bounded interval. In this case you could simply say that it is continuous because it is a polynomial, and all polynomials are continuous (it depends on how far you are in your analysis course before you can quote such results).

Comment: @Benedict "The user below has even recognized the numbers as coming up in a trigonometric identity. Unfortunately that wouldn't serve as a general method - only good for a few identities that can be recognized." As for this part, I'm really not sure why this has been directed at me. I'm not even sure that I understand what is being said here.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos 3 y=4\cos^3 y-3\cos y.$ When $\cos 3 y=-1/2$ and $x=\cos y$, we have $8 x^3-6 x +1=0,$ with $3$ solutions $x=\cos [2\pi(1+3 n)/9]$ for $n\in \{0,1,2\}.$

Comment: I recognized the polynomial right away. So I could bypass any general methods.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(x)=8x^3-6x+1$ the gradient function is $f'(x)=24x^2-6=6(4x^2-1).$ This leads to an observation about the ordinates of the stationary points. Then find $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$. The conclusion follows.